# Excel VBA: Replicating Index(Match()) between several arrays

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am attempting to automate a report that I currently prepare manually each month, but I'm having some issues getting it to run efficiently.  Basically, the report has 4 inputs:

1. Current Month YTD Spend & Savings Report (by part number) [70k rows x 4 cols]
2. Current Month Part Number lookup table [87k rows x 8 cols]
3. Previous Month YTD Spend & Savings Report (by part number) [60k rows x 4 cols]
4. Previous Month Part Number lookup table [77k rows x 8 cols]

As you can see, these are fairly sizable tables of information (certainly not the largest).  By year's end, I'd expect these tables to grow larger (maybe 25%) as we continue to release more part numbers.

My goal is to get one data table that combines all of these inputs and does some light mathematical calcs for a few columns.  Here's what my code looks like so far:

```
'Store data from 4 data worksheets into arrays
    Dim arrPrevDMCRLookup As Variant
        Dim lngFirstPDLRow As Long 'PDL = Previous DMCR Lookup
        Dim lngLastPDLRow As Long
        Dim lngNumPDLRows As Long
        Dim lngNumPDLCols As Long
        lngFirstPDLRow = 2 'Does not store header row
        lngLastPDLRow = wsPreviousLookupData.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        arrPrevDMCRLookup = wsPreviousLookupData.Range("A" & lngFirstPDLRow & ":H" & lngLastPDLRow)
        lngNumPDLRows = UBound(arrPrevDMCRLookup, 1) - LBound(arrPrevDMCRLookup, 1) + 1
        lngNumPDLCols = UBound(arrPrevDMCRLookup, 2) - LBound(arrPrevDMCRLookup, 2) + 1

    Dim arrPrevDMCRPivot As Variant
        Dim lngFirstPDPRow As Long 'PDP = Previous DMCR Pivot
        Dim lngLastPDPRow As Long
        Dim lngNumPDPRows As Long
        Dim lngNumPDPCols As Long
        lngFirstPDPRow = 5 'Does not store header row
        lngLastPDPRow = wsPreviousPivotSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        arrPrevDMCRPivot = wsPreviousPivotSheet.Range("A" & lngFirstPDPRow & ":D" & lngLastPDPRow)
        lngNumPDPRows = UBound(arrPrevDMCRPivot, 1) - LBound(arrPrevDMCRPivot, 1) + 1
        lngNumPDPCols = UBound(arrPrevDMCRPivot, 2) - LBound(arrPrevDMCRPivot, 2) + 1

    Dim arrCurrDMCRLookup As Variant
        Dim lngFirstCDLRow As Long 'CDL = Current DMCR Lookup
        Dim lngLastCDLRow As Long
        Dim lngNumCDLRows As Long
        Dim lngNumCDLCols As Long
        lngFirstCDLRow = 2 'Does not store header row
        lngLastCDLRow = wsCurrentLookupData.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        arrCurrDMCRLookup = wsCurrentLookupData.Range("A" & lngFirstCDLRow & ":H" & lngLastCDLRow)
        lngNumCDLRows = UBound(arrCurrDMCRLookup, 1) - LBound(arrCurrDMCRLookup, 1) + 1
        lngNumCDLCols = UBound(arrCurrDMCRLookup, 2) - LBound(arrCurrDMCRLookup, 2) + 1

    Dim arrCurrDMCRPivot As Variant
        Dim lngFirstCDPRow As Long 'CDP = Current DMCR Pivot
        Dim lngLastCDPRow As Long
        Dim lngNumCDPRows As Long
        Dim lngNumCDPCols As Long
        lngFirstCDPRow = 5 'Does not store header row
        lngLastCDPRow = wsCurrentPivotSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        arrCurrDMCRPivot = wsCurrentPivotSheet.Range("A" & lngFirstCDPRow & ":D" & lngLastCDPRow)
        lngNumCDPRows = UBound(arrCurrDMCRPivot, 1) - LBound(arrCurrDMCRPivot, 1) + 1
        lngNumCDPCols = UBound(arrCurrDMCRPivot, 2) - LBound(arrCurrDMCRPivot, 2) + 1

'Create array for output data
    Dim arrData As Variant
    ReDim arrData(1 To lngNumCDPRows, 1 To 21) 'arrData needs to have the same number of rows as arrCurrDMCRPivot and 21 columns

'Fill arrData
    Dim i As Long 'Loop variable
    Dim j As Long 'Loop variable
    For i = 1 To lngNumCDPRows

        'Update status bar
            Call UpdateStatusBar(1, lngNumCDPRows, i, "Combining reports...")

        'Grab data from arrCurrDMCRPivot
            arrData(i, 1) = arrCurrDMCRPivot(i, 1) 'Concatenate string
            arrData(i, 9) = arrCurrDMCRPivot(i, 2) 'Current Engineering Manager
            arrData(i, 10) = arrCurrDMCRPivot(i, 3) 'Current YTD USD Spend
            arrData(i, 11) = arrCurrDMCRPivot(i, 4) 'Current YTD USD Savings

        'Lookup data from arrCurrDMCRLookup
            For j = 1 To lngNumCDLRows
                If arrData(i, 1) = arrCurrDMCRLookup(j, 1) Then 'Concatenate strings match
                    arrData(i, 2) = arrCurrDMCRLookup(j, 2) 'Part number
                    arrData(i, 3) = arrCurrDMCRLookup(j, 3) 'Part name
                    arrData(i, 4) = arrCurrDMCRLookup(j, 4) 'Supplier Code
                    arrData(i, 5) = arrCurrDMCRLookup(j, 5) 'Supplier Name
                    arrData(i, 6) = arrCurrDMCRLookup(j, 6) 'DMCR Comp Grp
                    arrData(i, 7) = arrCurrDMCRLookup(j, 7) 'ACSD Org
                    arrData(i, 12) = arrCurrDMCRLookup(j, 8) 'Current DMCR: Prior Year Average Cost
                    Exit For 'Stop looking when a match was found
                End If
            Next j

        'Lookup data from arrPrevDMCRPivot
            For j = 1 To lngNumPDPRows
                If arrData(i, 1) = arrPrevDMCRPivot(j, 1) Then 'Concatenate strings match
                    arrData(i, 13) = arrPrevDMCRPivot(j, 2) 'Previous Engineering Manager
                    arrData(i, 14) = arrPrevDMCRPivot(j, 3) 'Previous YTD USD Spend
                    arrData(i, 15) = arrPrevDMCRPivot(j, 4) 'Previous YTD USD Savings
                    Exit For 'Stop looking when a match was found
                End If
            Next j

        'Lookup data from arrPrevDMCRLookup
            For j = 1 To lngNumPDLRows
                If arrData(i, 1) = arrPrevDMCRLookup(j, 1) Then 'Concatenate strings match
                    arrData(i, 16) = arrPrevDMCRLookup(j, 8) 'Previous DMCR: Prior Year Average Cost
                    Exit For 'Stop looking when a match was found
                End If
            Next j

        'Calculate remaining fields

    Next i
```

So as you can see, I'm using nested loops to replicate the functionality of Index(Match()) across my arrays.  However--this seems to be ridiculously slow!  Looking at my status bar update and I don't think I've seen it complete a row yet!

Right now, I'm looping through a potential 224k rows across 3 arrays for EACH ROW of my output array.  That's a potential 15.7 million rows to loop through!  There's got to be a better way to do this, right?  Would using

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(<column from one of the input arrays>, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(<concatenate string from output array>,<column from input array containing concatenate strings>,0))
```

work?  How would I specify the column from the input array that I want to look in?  Any tips for making this thing go at a more reasonable speed?

Thanks in advance for your help!!!

Comment: Quick note - an array picked from a worksheet range will always by one-based, so you can simplify your numRows/numcols assignments to just `UBound(array, [dimension])`

Comment: Does the data on each worksheet start on A1?

Comment: If you want to avoid the looping then you can create dictionary-based lookups into each array: that will be much faster.

Comment: Tim is right, loop once in the initialization to add items from, e.g., `arrCurrDMCRLookup` into a Dictionary. I'd suggest doing the value in the first column as a key, and the row number as the value. Then you can do something like `If DMCRLookupDictionary.Exists(arrData(i, 1)) Then arrData(i, 2) = arrCurrDMCRLookup(DMCRLookupDictionary(arrData(i, 1)), 2) ...` which is just looking up whether the key is in the dictionary, and if so retrieving it as the row index for your data copy.

Comment: Dictionaries are new to me, thanks for the suggestion!  Let me try implementing that...will let you know how it goes.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution would be to map all the rows in a `Collection`. It would be faster than a `Dictionary` by at least 30% and it's native to VBA.

Here is an example with your data:

```vb
Dim mapCurrDMCRLookup As Collection
Set mapCurrDMCRLookup = MapRows(arrCurrDMCRLookup, Column:=1)

For i = 1 To lngNumCDPRows

    'Lookup data from arrCurrDMCRLookup
    j = GetRow(mapCurrDMCRLookup, arrData(i, 1))
    If j > -1 Then   ' if found
        arrData(i, 2) = arrCurrDMCRLookup(j, 2) 'Part number
        ...
    End If

Next
```

```vb
Function MapRows(data(), Column As Integer) As Collection
    Set MapRows = New Collection
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim r As Long
    For r = LBound(data) To UBound(data)
      MapRows.Add r, CStr(data(r, Column))
    Next
End Function

Function GetRow(map As Collection, value) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    GetRow = -1
    GetRow = map(CStr(value))
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simplified example showing the general approach:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim i As Long, r As Long, v

    'main driving array
    Dim arrPrevDMCRPivot As Variant
    arrPrevDMCRPivot = GetData(wsPreviousPivotSheet)

    'array to be joined in....
    Dim arrPrevDMCRLookup As Variant, dictPrevDMCRLookup As Object
    arrPrevDMCRLookup = GetData(wsPreviousLookupData)
    Set dictPrevDMCRLookup = GetDict(arrPrevDMCRLookup, 1)

    'other arrays and lookups here....



    For i = 1 To UBound(arrPrevDMCRPivot)

        v = arrPrevDMCRPivot(i, 1) 'the lookup value
        If dictPrevDMCRLookup.exists(v) Then
            r = dictPrevDMCRLookup(v) 'r is the matching row in arrPrevDMCRLookup
            'use values from arrPrevDMCRLookup "row" r
            '.....
        End If

        'check other arrays/looups


    Next i

End Sub

Function GetData(sht As Worksheet)
    Dim arr
    With sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        arr = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Value
    End With
End Function

'get a lookup dictionary key=values from column [colNum], value=row
Function GetDict(arr, colNum As Long)
    Dim rv As Object, r As Long
    Set rv = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        If Not rv.exists(arr(r, colNum)) Then rv.Add arr(r, colNum), r
    Next r
    Set GetDict = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for this sample--I'll look into adapting this and get back to you.  Thanks again, Tim.

Comment: So I took your code and wrote it back in a way that I can understand--it's working almost flawlessly.  Entire runtime is about 60 seconds now, which is far better than I thought it'd be.

I'm having one more small problem.  Recall that I'm using concatenate strings for my keys in the dictionaries.  Some of the concatenate strings are alpha-numeric and the rest are numbers only.  It appears that all of the number-only concatenate strings are not being found when I look for them in the dictionaries.

I've tried formatting all the column A's as numbers but that isn't working.  Any thoughts?

Comment: FYI: I was able to solve this problem by making sure that I used Cstr(<concatenate string>) when I was adding the keys to the dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample of what I'm proposing, just for the first input table. You can extend this pattern to the rest of your lookup tables.

```
Dim DMCRLookupDictionary As New Dictionary
' ...
arrPrevDMCRLookup = wsPreviousLookupData.Range("A" & lngFirstPDLRow & ":H" & lngLastPDLRow)
lngNumPDLRows = UBound(arrPrevDMCRLookup, 1)
lngNumPDLCols = UBound(arrPrevDMCRLookup, 2)

' Build the dictionary mapping lookupKey -> lookupRow
Dim j As Long
For j = 1 To lngNumPDLRows
    If Not DMCRLookupDictionary.Exists(arrPrevDMCRLookup(j, 1)) Then
        DMCRLookupDictionary.Add(arrPrevDMCRLookup(j, 1), j)
    End If
Next j

' ...

For i = 1 To lngNumCDPRows
    ' ...

    If DMCRLookupDictionary.Exists(arrData(i, 1)) Then
        j = DMCRLookupDictionary(arrData(i, 1))

        arrData(i, 2) = arrCurrDMCRLookup(j, 2)
        arrData(i, 3) = arrCurrDMCRLookup(j, 3)
        ' ...
    End If
Next i
```

Do note that this will only match the first value encountered in the lookup table (but then, so does your sample code). Just be careful of duplicates.

Also requires you to import the scripting runtime to get access to the Dictionary class. `Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime` You can avoid this by creating your dictionaries as Tim did with `Dim DMCRLookupDictionary As Object: Set DMCRLookupDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`, but I tend to prefer adding a reference and getting better type-checking.

Comment: Thanks, Mike.  I will try this and let you know if I run into problems.